# Does infinite mass mean infinite gravitational force?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, universe

So, if I was to travel at speed of light, I would need infinite energy which means infinite mass. If I have infinte mass and energy I would bend space-time extreme. Does that mean that I would create so much gravitational force that I would be able to pull all things in universe on me (or destroy them). I know that we can't travel at speed of light because of infinite mass/energy but this is just theoretical question. And if I wrote something stupud, I'm sorry :) I'm stil beginner with our universe.

Comment: The theory does not work at all with massive objects traveling at light speed - you can't even sensibly mess with this idea on paper.

Comment: So my idea makes no sense. I would appriciate if somebody could explain where my theroy falls apart and what I did wrong. And yeah, what is hyperspace?

Comment: It's like asking "what is the value of $1/0$? I know we can't divide anything by zero but this is just a theoretical question". Well, precisely, the theory tells that it does not make sense. Same here: massive objects can not travel at the speed of light, so the question does not make sense. That is what the theory says.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Who knows? You may modify your body to have infinite mass. But the problem is you're still moving and acc. To relativity there is nothing to do while you're going that fast. Time stops.
Also the bend in the space-time would be almost negligible since you'd be moving away from one point to another at a speed second to none.
Hope this satisfies the problem.